# Array to string conversion on running my website's server code on local host

Tags: php, joomla, localhost

I am using joomla 3.5.0. I am trying to run my server code on my local host using xamp. I am getting the following error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 356

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 358

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 361

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 365

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 356

The code is: lines 353 to 366

```
// Traverse the registry to find the correct node for the result.
            for ($i = 0, $n = count($nodes) - 1; $i < $n; $i++)
            {
                if (!isset($node->$nodes[$i]) && ($i != $n))
                {
                    $node->$nodes[$i] = new stdClass;
                }

                $node = (object) $node->$nodes[$i];
            }

            // Get the old value if exists so we can return it
            $result = $node->$nodes[$i] = $value;
        }
```

I have configured the configuration.php file as well.

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, like @Navnit said, *have you any code??* ;)

Comment: I am new to joomla. i got the zip file of the code and tried to run it using xamp local host.

Comment: I think the code should be fine as it is running very well on server but not on my machine.

Comment: You should show us what you have in that file (`registry.php`) around line 356. We're developers, not mediums.

Comment: @phaberest Speak for yourself. I can *sense* that he has some sort of *array* which is being implicitly cast as something called a *string*...

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda that must be what that _arcane_ in your username means!

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the code above. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xampp sometimes seems problematic running Joomla on certain environments. You can try Wamp Server, similar stack alternative.**

[Read more Joomla forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=707&p=3384565)